# Concourse Pipeline: How to have an Embedded Script Fail the Pipeline

Tags: python, concourse, concourse-pipeline

When I run a Concourse pipeline with a nested Python script inside of the run param like so:

```
- task: some-task
    params:
      ...
    config:
      platform: linux
      ...
      run:
        path: bash
        args:
        - "-c"
        - |

          python my_failing_python_code.py
```

When the python script fails, throwing an exit 1, the error does not seem to bubble up to the pipeline like I would expect. Overall the pipeline ends "successfully".

How should I set up my pipeline to read the exit status of a script run within the pipeline?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is the whole content of the script, then you can replace it with

```
run:
        path: python
        args:
        - my_failing_python_code.py
```

See https://concourse-ci.org/hello-world-example.html

if the shell script does also other things, you are missing a `set -e`, to tell the shell to report an error:

```
    run:
        path: bash
        args:
        - "-c"
        - |
          set -e
          python my_failing_python_code.py
```

See https://concourse-ci.org/tasks.html

Comment: There is more to the script, I run some bash setup then invoke the python script. I will implement the `set -e` and report back. Thank you!